# google compute engine taking time to load response for website

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a website running on google compute engine. In my site i fill one form and I wait for response generated by site. But it takes almost 10-15 sec to load response. Form is same like `http://fivefilters.org/content-only/`.
I want to avoid this slow responses.
For that how do i complete the process in short time.

**I am running my instance on f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory) machine**

[image]

Is it because of f1-micro machine??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your web site write to disk at all when serving the request? If the instance has a small disk (ie 10gb) it only gets a fraction of disk time for its writes which can easily end up being the bottleneck.

But also, f1-micro is a small instance type and depending on what the site does, anything could impede it's progress.

In case you don't want to log into the instance and debug/trace locally, temporarily try a disk of at least 100gb if there are any disk writes at all and a bigger instance type, at least n1-standard-1.

Comment: Okay i will try n1-standard-1 for test it out

Comment: I'd really like to emphasise the disk size as well, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#pdperformance. A 10gb disk will start blocking for a small number of writes per second.

Comment: I implemented on 'n1-standard-1' but no improvement. I will try your suggestion now.