# Why my website that is deployed in Google compute engine VM instance taking too long to load?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, mern

My website is taking too much time to load. I have hosted it in a VM instance created from Google compute engine.

My website is built on MERN stack and running with docker compose. I'm using docker scaling for backend application but no load balancing for the client side or the VM.

I would really appreciate if someone helps me out with this issue, I've been searching for days but still couldn't figure out what the issue is.

This is the site link:
https://www.mindschoolbd.com

VM type: e2-standard-2,
zone: nortamerica-norteast2-a

Comment: Can you please share your running VM instance details(type)?

Comment: How long does it take to load for you? It seemed quite fast on my end

Comment: Earlier it was taking around 10 seconds, now it is quite fast on my end also. Refer to this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620263/google-compute-engine-taking-time-to-load-response-for-website) which help to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with vm type and config. The initial loading time is quite long. 20-30s. I'm in Bangladesh. The VM is on northameria region. I have tried another VM with asia region but the result was same there.

Comment: For me it takes 2 to 3 seconds.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg thats the issue. Some where its taking long time to load, somewhere its very fast. I'm not sure whats wrong with this one

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy Its still not solved. Couldn't find any solution till now

Comment: Posted answer, let me know if further info is required.

Answer (score 1):

**There are few things that we can do to make it load fast :**

1)You can optimize your application code (including database queries if you have) - on this part, you can contact your developer as this is out of our scope as well.

**Check there are a few situations that may cause the load issue in mobile apps:**

i)The MERN Stack - A Practical guide app server may be down and that is causing the loading issue.

ii)Your wifi / mobile data connection is not working properly. Please check your data connection.

iii)Too many users are using the app at the same time. Please try after a few minutes.

Please go through the [MERN Stack practical issues](https://www.99images.com/apps/education/learn.mern.stack_softdroid/problems) for more info.

2)You can upgrade your Machine type and this includes the CPU and RAM of your VM instance and server caching is also part of it.
Check over util of memory and cpu increase, if required change it into something higher than e2-standard-2, As recommended in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620263/google-compute-engine-taking-time-to-load-response-for-website) for more information.

3)Try to have your vm deployed in a region which is near to your location. Suggest to create snapshot and create vm using snapshot and change region.

4)Create a cloud CDN for caching to make it load fast, [Cloud CDN lowers network latency](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/locations) & [Content delivery best practices](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/best-practices), offloads origins, and reduces serving costs. Recommending to use [Optimize application latency with load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/optimize-app-latency) and also installing an [Ops agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation) in your VM instance to have a better monitoring view.

Finally go through the [Website Speed Optimization Tips: Techniques to Improve Performance and User Experience](https://sematext.com/blog/improve-website-performance/) for more information.